# Landing page for shopware using shopping worlds

Tags: e-commerce, smarty, shopware

How do I integrate **shopping worlds** which I created as Landing page for shopware. I did found in SEO url settings ->SEO URLs landing page template:{$campaign.name} where you configure this. Is this correct. I also completed seo url rebuild.

But still the landing page is empty. Can anyone explain how to configure the landing page for Shopware eCommerce.

[image: shopping worlds settings]

Comment: The Answer should be tied within there FAQ or KB.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get what you're referring to.